# Change URL of parent with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, url, radio-button

I have a menu with different sections, these sections filter some results depending their "section" (which can be 1, 2 or 3):

```
<div class="menu">
<label class="section" ng-click="changeLoc('Section1')">
  <input type="radio" id="optradio" ng-model="searchText.Section" value="1">
  <p>Section 1</p>
</label>

<label class="section" ng-click="changeLoc('Section2')">
  <input type="radio" id="optradio" ng-model="searchText.Section" value="2">
  <p>Section 2</p>
</label>

<label class="section" ng-click="changeLoc('Section3')">
  <input type="radio" id="optradio" ng-model="searchText.Section" value="3">
  <p>Section 3</p>
</label>
</div>
```

I want the site URL to change depending the section clicked

> **Example of normal url**: www.normal-site.com
>
> **Example with a section clicked**: www.normal-site.com/Section1

The problem is that my code is inside an iFrame.
I have a script like this:

```
$scope.changeLoc = function(newRoute) {
   $location.path(newRoute);
}
```

...but the parent site won't change the URL. I tried something like this, but I doesn't work:

```
$scope.changeLoc = function(newRoute) {
   parent.$location.path(newRoute);
}
```

**Also** I wish to know how to have a certain section checked if people enter the URL with the specific path written. Example: people write *"www.normal-site.com/Section2"*, and the "section 2" input to be checked when the page loads.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend re-evaluating your approach to this. Rather than using iFrames, I suggest a routing approach with sub-views. It looks like you are trying to overcome some obstacles that routing would remove altogether.

Comment: @Lex the problem is I can't redo the whole site, I'm just working with this part which is made with AngularJS and is inside an iframe